# Several identical AJAX functions to one

Tags: ajax, function

Suppose we have three (or hundred) identical AJAX functions :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function vote1(url)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("voting1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}


function vote2(url)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("voting2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}



function vote3(url)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("voting3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

</script>
```

And we have three (or hundred) identical buttons in foreach loop :

```
<div id="voting1">
<form><input type="button" onclick="vote1('votes.php?parameter1')" value="vote">
</form></div>

<div id="voting2">
<form><input type="button" onclick="vote2('votes.php?parameter2')" value="vote">
</form></div>

<div id="voting3">
<form><input type="button" onclick="vote3('votes.php?parameter3')" value="vote">
</form></div>
```

The reason to have separate function for every button is the different output on every button, based on the different parameter string_ID for ex.. 
The question is - how to combine all of the AJAX functions into one AJAX function, keeping in mind that buttons are in foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Create one function called vote, that accepts the id of the element as parameter:

```
function vote(id, url)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And then just pass your variable stuff to your html like that (I'm assuming a php for-loop but could be anything):

```
<?php
for ($i=0 ; $i<$max ; $i++) {
  ?>
  <div id="voting<?php echo $i; ?>">
  <form><input type="button" onclick="vote('voting<?php echo $i; ?>', 'votes.php?parameter<?php echo $i; ?>')" value="vote">
  </form></div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The output will be the same on all buttons, but should be just on one. Others should remain the same.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pass the id into the function in the onclick argument of the button (I've updated my answer). To ensure that it works how it should, ensure that every div has a unique id like vote1, vote2, vote3, etc. and the same id is passed into the vote function.